# How To delete specific symbols from a linux file?

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

My Linux file contains of over 4000 lines of code similar to this:

```
[INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:57','Electrolux', 'abandoned', '1609507904.86839', 'ROUTING_SCRIPT', 'Electrolux', '01008367900', '886123', 'CALL')]
[INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:59','Electrolux-Inst', 'queued', '1609507878.86832', 'VIRTUAL', 'Electrolux', '01552050703', '886123', 'CALL')]
[INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:59','Electrolux', 'distributed', '1609507878.86832', 'ROUTING_SCRIPT', 'Electrolux', '01552050703', '886123', 'CALL')]
[INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:59','Electrolux-Inst', 'distributed', '1609507878.86832', 'VIRTUAL', 'Electrolux', '01552050703', '886123', 'CALL')]
```

I need linux command(s) to delete the square brackets [    ] from the file so that it looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:57','Electrolux', 'abandoned', '1609507904.86839', 'ROUTING_SCRIPT', 'Electrolux', '01008367900', '886123', 'CALL')
INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:59','Electrolux-Inst', 'queued', '1609507878.86832', 'VIRTUAL', 'Electrolux', '01552050703', '886123', 'CALL')
INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:59','Electrolux', 'distributed', '1609507878.86832', 'ROUTING_SCRIPT', 'Electrolux', '01552050703', '886123', 'CALL')
INSERT INTO DATAMART_QUEUE_DETAILS(EVENT_TIME,QUEUE,EVENT,TRACKNUM,QUEUE_TYPE,ASSOCIATED_ROUTING_SCRIPT,ANI,DNIS,CHANNEL_TYPE) VALUES ('2021.01.01 15:31:59','Electrolux-Inst', 'distributed', '1609507878.86832', 'VIRTUAL', 'Electrolux', '01552050703', '886123', 'CALL')
```

Finally, I want to insert these lines directly to MySQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheap and cheerful way is

```
tr -d '[]' < infile > outfile
```

Edit: I should add that this won't have the desired result if [ or ] occurs in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question already has an answer, I'd like to share my own solution here:

`cat infile | sed 's/^\[\(.*\)\]$/\1/' > outfile`

Explanation:

- `s`: substitute command `s/regexp/replacement/flags`
- `^`: start of string
- `\[`: The literal character `[`
- `\(.*\)`: A group that captures everything
- `\]`: The literal character `]`
- `$`: end of string
- `\1`: text in the first capturing group (`\(.*\)`)

EDIT: in fact, this solution works even if there are '[' or ']' inside the input